# How can I extract a multi-substrings from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I need help with extracting multiple substrings from a string and assign it to a list, and those required substrings have similar start substring and end substring,

for example if I have a string like this: "start something something end start nothing nothing end"

how do I extract "something something" and "nothing nothing" and append it to a list.

Comment: Extract them based on what? If you know "something something" can't you just create a string containing "something something"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and then read [ask].

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for but have a look at the re module. It should be able to get you where you want if you are looking at extracting words based on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
>>> text = 'start something something end start nothing nothing end'
>>> re.findall('start (.+?) end', text)
['something something', 'nothing nothing']
```

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Pattern is

- `start` followed by a space
- the `(` indicates the start of the part (group) we're interested in
- the `.` indicates arbitrary character
- the `+?` indicates at least one, but as little as possible
- the `)` indicates the end of the part (group) wer're interested in
- a space followed by `end`.

> The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order  found.
>
> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
> groups;

We're using groups, as shown above

> this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
> group.

We only use one group.

> Empty matches are included in the result.

Comment: This should also work fine `str = [string.split("start")[1].strip() for string in str.split("end")[:-1]]`. See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinLightcoralCategory).